# Name casing convention across all languages in an Application

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, json, naming-conventions

I'm build a web app using Javascript (on the browser), C# and Sql Server. Is it a good idea to have a consistent naming convention across all three languages?
For Javscript, it seems to be best practice is to use camelCase, but in C# and Sql Server it's TitleCase.
Problem though is when the Javascript consumes and sends data to C# / Sql server the naming conventions are inconsistent.  So I have to write code to map them.

For example

> In Sql I have a table called 'Foo' with columns 'Name', 'EmailAddress'
>
> In C# I have an POCO object called 'Foo' that maps to this table with
>   properties 'Name', 'EmailAddress'  and exposes an api endpoint to GET this is 
>   json 
>   e.g {"Name": "Joe Bloggs", "EmailAddres":"joe@test.org"}
>
> My Javascripts makes an ajax call to GET this JSON and maps it to its own
>   JSON object e.g {"name": data.Name, "emailAddress": data.EmailAddress}

This mapping between column/property naming conventions seems silly to me, and wouldn't be needed if all languages just agreed on casing convention.  Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: I don't think there's a lot of value in it, but I will say that we use camelCase for variable names (@variableName) in SQL which is consistent with the naming convention used in C# and JavaScript... but that's probably the only thing we do at my company along these lines. Table names & Column names are still TitleCase (like class names in C#) For JavaScript... we just do mappings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you should continue to use the standard conventions for each language.

Benefits:

- Consistency in each piece of software.
- Easier for your fellow developer, since they won't need to learn a homebrew naming convention(s).
- It will be easier to communicate code to the rest of the world in places like SO, or if you decide to to implement a solution found on SO.

Don't add extra conventions just to make the languages consistent. Your languages will end up with meaningless rules that are not relevant, and it'll be confusing to anyone who works on your code in the future.

To play Devil's Advocate, here's an opinion that disagrees with mine stolen from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205535/java-naming-conventions-vs-c-c-naming-conventions):

> This is where you find the big issue with coding standards based on
>   style - if your team doesn't write the entire codebase, then you're
>   going to find you have mismatches with the other code's standard.
>
> So, my advice is not to sweat it. As long as your code is clear, it
>   really doesn't matter whether you use camel case, pascal case, or
>   underscore style. Its more important that the code is readable.
>
> You should never alter the style of the 3rd parties as that will make
>   comparison with new versions impossible, so you have to stick with
>   them. If you have 2 different-style libraries, you have no choice but
>   to follow a standard that ignores code style. Its not that bad, if
>   you're a good coder you can read any code style. If you're not, having
>   a solitary style won't help you at all.

I include it because I think they make a good point, and because you're working on your own code outside of a team context. However, it's always good to practice good habits (or rather, avoid bad habits) on side projects, since they might carry through to code you write with/for others, so it would be beneficial to learn how to deal with naming conventions on a large codebase if you think you'll run into that issue in the future while on a team.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your application startup, and it should automatically convert the returned object of your GET to camelCase.

No need to futz with any mappings or stray from the conventions of each environment.

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

See here for more detail: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/25/asp-net-webapi-tip-3-camelcasing-json.aspx